Cross-compile onnxruntime (x86 to aarch64) with CUDA support
as the question suggests I'm trying to cross-compile the onnxruntime library (v1.19.2) on my host machine Ubuntu 22.04 x86_64 for the target aarch64 (NVidia Jetson Orin Nano).
I was able to:

Compile the library with only CPU support for host
Compile the library with CUDA support for host
Cross-compile the library with only CPU support for target

Here are the steps I've been following:

Clone the repository with the right tag
git clone --recursive https://github.com/microsoft/onnxruntime.git -b v1.19.2

Modify the cmake/linux_arm64_crosscompile_toolchain.cmake file content to specify the cross-compilers aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc and aarch64-linux-gnu-g++

Download and install the host CUDA Toolkit 12.6


wget https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2204/x86_64/cuda-ubuntu2204.pin
mv cuda-ubuntu2204.pin /etc/apt/preferences.d/cuda-repository-pin-600
wget https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/12.6.2/local_installers/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-6-local_12.6.2-560.35.03-1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-6-local_12.6.2-560.35.03-1_amd64.deb
sudo cp /var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-6-local/cuda-*-keyring.gpg /usr/share/keyrings/
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y install cuda-toolkit-12-6


Download and install the CUDNN Toolkit 9.5.1

wget https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cudnn/9.5.1/local_installers/cudnn-local-repo-ubuntu2204-9.5.1_1.0-1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i cudnn-local-repo-ubuntu2204-9.5.1_1.0-1_amd64.deb
sudo cp /var/cudnn-local-repo-ubuntu2204-9.5.1/cudnn-*-keyring.gpg /usr/share/keyrings/
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y install cudnn


Download and install the CUDA Toolkit 12.6 for cross-compilation x86 to aarch64

wget https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/12.6.2/local_installers/cuda-repo-cross-aarch64-ubuntu2204-12-6-local_12.6.2-1_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-cross-aarch64-ubuntu2204-12-6-local_12.6.2-1_all.deb
sudo cp /var/cuda-repo-cross-aarch64-ubuntu2204-12-6-local/cuda-*-keyring.gpg /usr/share/keyrings/
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y install cuda-cross-aarch64


Download and install the CUDNN Toolkit 9.5.1 for cross-compilation x86 to aarch64

wget https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cudnn/9.5.1/local_installers/cudnn-local-repo-cross-aarch64-ubuntu2204-9.5.1_1.0-1_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i cudnn-local-repo-cross-aarch64-ubuntu2204-9.5.1_1.0-1_all.deb
sudo cp /var/cudnn-local-repo-cross-aarch64-ubuntu2204-9.5.1/cudnn-*-keyring.gpg /usr/share/keyrings/
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y install cudnn-cross-aarch64


Start the build

export CUDA_HOME=/usr/local/cuda
export CUDNN_HOME=/usr/local/cuda

./build.sh --build_dir aarch64-build-gpu/ --config Release --update --build --parallel --build_shared_lib --skip_tests --cmake_extra_defines CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/root/onnxruntime/cmake/linux_arm64_crosscompile_toolchain.cmake CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/root/onnxruntime/aarch64-install-gpu/ --use_cuda --allow_running_as_root

Here is the partial build log
[  2%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/onnxruntime_mlas.dir/root/onnxruntime/onnxruntime/core/mlas/lib/halfgemm.cpp.o
[  2%] Building CXX object _deps/protobuf-build/CMakeFiles/libprotobuf-lite.dir/src/google/protobuf/repeated_field.cc.o
[  2%] Generating cpp/platform/posix/src/per_thread_waiter.c
[  2%] Generating cpp/internal/common.c
[  2%] Generating cpp/internal/counter.c
[  2%] Generating cpp/internal/cv.c
[  3%] Generating cpp/internal/debug.c
[  3%] Generating cpp/internal/dll.c
[  3%] Generating cpp/internal/mu.c
[  3%] Generating cpp/internal/mu_wait.c
[  3%] Generating cpp/internal/note.c
[  3%] Generating cpp/internal/once.c
[  3%] Generating cpp/internal/sem_wait.c
[  3%] Generating cpp/internal/time_internal.c
[  3%] Generating cpp/internal/wait.c
[  3%] Generating cpp/platform/c++11/src/nsync_panic.cc
[  3%] Generating cpp/platform/c++11/src/time_rep_timespec.cc
[  3%] Generating cpp/platform/c++11/src/yield.cc
[  3%] Generating cpp/platform/linux/src/nsync_semaphore_futex.c
[  3%] Building CXX object _deps/google_nsync-build/CMakeFiles/nsync_cpp.dir/cpp/internal/common.c.o
[  3%] Building CXX object _deps/google_nsync-build/CMakeFiles/nsync_cpp.dir/cpp/internal/counter.c.o
[  3%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/onnxruntime_mlas.dir/root/onnxruntime/onnxruntime/core/mlas/lib/qgemm.cpp.o
[  3%] Building CXX object _deps/google_nsync-build/CMakeFiles/nsync_cpp.dir/cpp/internal/cv.c.o
[  3%] Building CXX object _deps/google_nsync-build/CMakeFiles/nsync_cpp.dir/cpp/internal/debug.c.o
[  3%] Building CXX object _deps/google_nsync-build/CMakeFiles/nsync_cpp.dir/cpp/internal/dll.c.o
[  3%] Building CXX object _deps/protobuf-build/CMakeFiles/libprotobuf-lite.dir/src/google/protobuf/repeated_ptr_field.cc.o
[  3%] Building CXX object _deps/google_nsync-build/CMakeFiles/nsync_cpp.dir/cpp/internal/mu.c.o
[  4%] Building CXX object _deps/google_nsync-build/CMakeFiles/nsync_cpp.dir/cpp/internal/mu_wait.c.o
[  4%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/onnxruntime_providers_shared.dir/root/onnxruntime/onnxruntime/core/providers/shared/common.cc.o
[  4%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/onnxruntime_mlas.dir/root/onnxruntime/onnxruntime/core/mlas/lib/qdwconv.cpp.o
[  4%] Building CXX object _deps/google_nsync-build/CMakeFiles/nsync_cpp.dir/cpp/internal/note.c.o
[  4%] Linking CXX shared library libonnxruntime_providers_shared.so
[  4%] Built target onnxruntime_providers_shared
[  4%] Building CXX object _deps/flatbuffers-build/CMakeFiles/flatc.dir/src/idl_gen_java.cpp.o
[  4%] Building CXX object _deps/protobuf-build/CMakeFiles/libprotobuf-lite.dir/src/google/protobuf/stubs/bytestream.cc.o
[  4%] Building CXX object _deps/google_nsync-build/CMakeFiles/nsync_cpp.dir/cpp/internal/once.c.o
[  4%] Building CXX object _deps/protobuf-build/CMakeFiles/libprotobuf-lite.dir/src/google/protobuf/stubs/common.cc.o
[  4%] Building CXX object _deps/google_nsync-build/CMakeFiles/nsync_cpp.dir/cpp/internal/sem_wait.c.o
[  4%] Linking CXX static library libflatbuffers.a
[  4%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/onnxruntime_mlas.dir/root/onnxruntime/onnxruntime/core/mlas/lib/convolve.cpp.o
[  4%] Built target flatbuffers
[  4%] Building CXX object _deps/google_nsync-build/CMakeFiles/nsync_cpp.dir/cpp/internal/time_internal.c.o
[  4%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/onnxruntime_mlas.dir/root/onnxruntime/onnxruntime/core/mlas/lib/convsym.cpp.o
[  4%] Building CXX object _deps/google_nsync-build/CMakeFiles/nsync_cpp.dir/cpp/internal/wait.c.o
[  4%] Building CXX object _deps/google_nsync-build/CMakeFiles/nsync_cpp.dir/cpp/platform/linux/src/nsync_semaphore_futex.c.o
[  4%] Building CXX object _deps/protobuf-build/CMakeFiles/libprotobuf-lite.dir/src/google/protobuf/stubs/int128.cc.o
[  4%] Building CXX object _deps/flatbuffers-build/CMakeFiles/flatc.dir/src/idl_gen_ts.cpp.o
[  4%] Building CXX object _deps/google_nsync-build/CMakeFiles/nsync_cpp.dir/cpp/platform/posix/src/per_thread_waiter.c.o
[  4%] Building CXX object _deps/google_nsync-build/CMakeFiles/nsync_cpp.dir/cpp/platform/c++11/src/yield.cc.o
[  4%] Building CXX object _deps/protobuf-build/CMakeFiles/libprotobuf-lite.dir/src/google/protobuf/stubs/status.cc.o
[  4%] Building CXX object _deps/google_nsync-build/CMakeFiles/nsync_cpp.dir/cpp/platform/c++11/src/time_rep_timespec.cc.o
[  4%] Building CXX object _deps/protobuf-build/CMakeFiles/libprotobuf-lite.dir/src/google/protobuf/stubs/statusor.cc.o
[  4%] Building CXX object _deps/google_nsync-build/CMakeFiles/nsync_cpp.dir/cpp/platform/c++11/src/nsync_panic.cc.o
[  4%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/onnxruntime_mlas.dir/root/onnxruntime/onnxruntime/core/mlas/lib/pooling.cpp.o
[  4%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/onnxruntime_mlas.dir/root/onnxruntime/onnxruntime/core/mlas/lib/transpose.cpp.o
[  4%] Building CXX object _deps/protobuf-build/CMakeFiles/libprotobuf-lite.dir/src/google/protobuf/stubs/stringpiece.cc.o
[  4%] Linking CXX static library libnsync_cpp.a
[  4%] Built target nsync_cpp
[  4%] Generating onnxruntime.lds, generated_source.c
Generating symbol file for ['cpu', 'cuda']
VERSION:1.19.2
[  4%] Built target onnxruntime_generate_def
[  4%] Building CXX object _deps/protobuf-build/CMakeFiles/libprotobuf-lite.dir/src/google/protobuf/stubs/stringprintf.cc.o
[  4%] Building C object _deps/pytorch_clog-build/CMakeFiles/clog.dir/src/clog.c.o
[  4%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/onnxruntime_mlas.dir/root/onnxruntime/onnxruntime/core/mlas/lib/reorder.cpp.o
/root/onnxruntime/aarch64-build-gpu/Release/_deps/pytorch_clog-src/deps/clog/src/clog.c: In function ‘clog_vlog_fatal’:
/root/onnxruntime/aarch64-build-gpu/Release/_deps/pytorch_clog-src/deps/clog/src/clog.c:117:25: warning: ignoring return value of ‘write’ declared with attribute ‘warn_unused_result’ [-Wunused-result]
  117 |                         write(STDERR_FILENO, out_buffer, prefix_chars + format_chars + CLOG_SUFFIX_LENGTH);
      |                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/root/onnxruntime/aarch64-build-gpu/Release/_deps/pytorch_clog-src/deps/clog/src/clog.c: In function ‘clog_vlog_error’:
/root/onnxruntime/aarch64-build-gpu/Release/_deps/pytorch_clog-src/deps/clog/src/clog.c:195:25: warning: ignoring return value of ‘write’ declared with attribute ‘warn_unused_result’ [-Wunused-result]
  195 |                         write(STDERR_FILENO, out_buffer, prefix_chars + format_chars + CLOG_SUFFIX_LENGTH);
      |                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/root/onnxruntime/aarch64-build-gpu/Release/_deps/pytorch_clog-src/deps/clog/src/clog.c: In function ‘clog_vlog_warning’:
/root/onnxruntime/aarch64-build-gpu/Release/_deps/pytorch_clog-src/deps/clog/src/clog.c:273:25: warning: ignoring return value of ‘write’ declared with attribute ‘warn_unused_result’ [-Wunused-result]
  273 |                         write(STDERR_FILENO, out_buffer, prefix_chars + format_chars + CLOG_SUFFIX_LENGTH);
      |                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/root/onnxruntime/aarch64-build-gpu/Release/_deps/pytorch_clog-src/deps/clog/src/clog.c: In function ‘clog_vlog_info’:
/root/onnxruntime/aarch64-build-gpu/Release/_deps/pytorch_clog-src/deps/clog/src/clog.c:351:25: warning: ignoring return value of ‘write’ declared with attribute ‘warn_unused_result’ [-Wunused-result]
  351 |                         write(STDOUT_FILENO, out_buffer, prefix_chars + format_chars + CLOG_SUFFIX_LENGTH);
      |                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/root/onnxruntime/aarch64-build-gpu/Release/_deps/pytorch_clog-src/deps/clog/src/clog.c: In function ‘clog_vlog_debug’:
/root/onnxruntime/aarch64-build-gpu/Release/_deps/pytorch_clog-src/deps/clog/src/clog.c:429:25: warning: ignoring return value of ‘write’ declared with attribute ‘warn_unused_result’ [-Wunused-result]
  429 |                         write(STDOUT_FILENO, out_buffer, prefix_chars + format_chars + CLOG_SUFFIX_LENGTH);
      |                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[  4%] Linking C static library libclog.a
[  4%] Built target clog
[  4%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/onnxruntime_mocked_allocator.dir/root/onnxruntime/onnxruntime/test/util/test_allocator.cc.o
[  4%] Building CUDA object CMakeFiles/custom_op_library.dir/root/onnxruntime/onnxruntime/test/shared_lib/cuda_ops.cu.o
[  4%] Building CXX object _deps/protobuf-build/CMakeFiles/libprotobuf-lite.dir/src/google/protobuf/stubs/structurally_valid.cc.o
[  4%] Building CXX object _deps/protobuf-build/CMakeFiles/libprotobuf-lite.dir/src/google/protobuf/stubs/strutil.cc.o
[  4%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/custom_op_invalid_library.dir/root/onnxruntime/onnxruntime/test/testdata/custom_op_invalid_library/custom_op_library.cc.o
[  4%] Linking CXX shared module libcustom_op_invalid_library.so
[  4%] Built target custom_op_invalid_library
[  4%] Building CXX object _deps/flatbuffers-build/CMakeFiles/flatc.dir/src/idl_gen_php.cpp.o
[  5%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/custom_op_library.dir/root/onnxruntime/onnxruntime/test/testdata/custom_op_library/cpu/cpu_ops.cc.o
[  5%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/onnxruntime_mlas.dir/root/onnxruntime/onnxruntime/core/mlas/lib/snchwc.cpp.o
[  5%] Linking CXX static library libonnxruntime_mocked_allocator.a
[  5%] Built target onnxruntime_mocked_allocator
[  5%] Building CXX object _deps/protobuf-build/CMakeFiles/libprotobuf-lite.dir/src/google/protobuf/stubs/time.cc.o
[  5%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/custom_op_library.dir/root/onnxruntime/onnxruntime/test/testdata/custom_op_library/cuda/cuda_ops.cc.o
[  5%] Building CXX object _deps/protobuf-build/CMakeFiles/libprotobuf-lite.dir/src/google/protobuf/wire_format_lite.cc.o
[  5%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/onnxruntime_mlas.dir/root/onnxruntime/onnxruntime/core/mlas/lib/activate.cpp.o
[  5%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/onnxruntime_mlas.dir/root/onnxruntime/onnxruntime/core/mlas/lib/logistic.cpp.o
[  5%] Linking CXX static library libprotobuf-lite.a
[  5%] Built target libprotobuf-lite
[  5%] Building CXX object _deps/flatbuffers-build/CMakeFiles/flatc.dir/src/idl_gen_python.cpp.o
[  5%] Building CXX object _deps/flatbuffers-build/CMakeFiles/flatc.dir/src/idl_gen_lobster.cpp.o
[  5%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/onnxruntime_mlas.dir/root/onnxruntime/onnxruntime/core/mlas/lib/tanh.cpp.o
[  5%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/onnxruntime_mlas.dir/root/onnxruntime/onnxruntime/core/mlas/lib/erf.cpp.o
[  5%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/onnxruntime_mlas.dir/root/onnxruntime/onnxruntime/core/mlas/lib/compute.cpp.o
[  5%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/custom_op_get_const_input_test_library.dir/root/onnxruntime/onnxruntime/test/testdata/custom_op_get_const_input_test_library/custom_op.cc.o
[  5%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/custom_op_library.dir/root/onnxruntime/onnxruntime/test/testdata/custom_op_library/custom_op_library.cc.o
[  6%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/onnxruntime_mlas.dir/root/onnxruntime/onnxruntime/core/mlas/lib/quantize.cpp.o
[  6%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/custom_op_get_const_input_test_library.dir/root/onnxruntime/onnxruntime/test/testdata/custom_op_get_const_input_test_library/custom_op_lib.cc.o
[  6%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/onnxruntime_mlas.dir/root/onnxruntime/onnxruntime/core/mlas/lib/qgemm_kernel_default.cpp.o
[  6%] Building CXX object _deps/flatbuffers-build/CMakeFiles/flatc.dir/src/idl_gen_rust.cpp.o
[  6%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/custom_op_local_function.dir/root/onnxruntime/onnxruntime/test/testdata/custom_op_local_function/custom_op_local_function.cc.o
[  6%] Building CXX object _deps/flatbuffers-build/CMakeFiles/flatc.dir/src/idl_gen_fbs.cpp.o
[  6%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/custom_op_local_function.dir/root/onnxruntime/onnxruntime/test/testdata/custom_op_local_function/dummy_gemm.cc.o
[  6%] Linking CXX shared module libcustom_op_get_const_input_test_library.so
[  6%] Linking CXX shared library libcustom_op_library.so
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/custom_op_library.dir/root/onnxruntime/onnxruntime/test/shared_lib/cuda_ops.cu.o: Relocations in generic ELF (EM: 62)
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/custom_op_library.dir/root/onnxruntime/onnxruntime/test/shared_lib/cuda_ops.cu.o: Relocations in generic ELF (EM: 62)
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/custom_op_library.dir/root/onnxruntime/onnxruntime/test/shared_lib/cuda_ops.cu.o: Relocations in generic ELF (EM: 62)
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/custom_op_library.dir/root/onnxruntime/onnxruntime/test/shared_lib/cuda_ops.cu.o: Relocations in generic ELF (EM: 62)
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/custom_op_library.dir/root/onnxruntime/onnxruntime/test/shared_lib/cuda_ops.cu.o: Relocations in generic ELF (EM: 62)
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/custom_op_library.dir/root/onnxruntime/onnxruntime/test/shared_lib/cuda_ops.cu.o: Relocations in generic ELF (EM: 62)
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/custom_op_library.dir/root/onnxruntime/onnxruntime/test/shared_lib/cuda_ops.cu.o: Relocations in generic ELF (EM: 62)
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/custom_op_library.dir/root/onnxruntime/onnxruntime/test/shared_lib/cuda_ops.cu.o: Relocations in generic ELF (EM: 62)
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/custom_op_library.dir/root/onnxruntime/onnxruntime/test/shared_lib/cuda_ops.cu.o: Relocations in generic ELF (EM: 62)
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/custom_op_library.dir/root/onnxruntime/onnxruntime/test/shared_lib/cuda_ops.cu.o: Relocations in generic ELF (EM: 62)
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/custom_op_library.dir/root/onnxruntime/onnxruntime/test/shared_lib/cuda_ops.cu.o: Relocations in generic ELF (EM: 62)
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/custom_op_library.dir/root/onnxruntime/onnxruntime/test/shared_lib/cuda_ops.cu.o: Relocations in generic ELF (EM: 62)
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/custom_op_library.dir/root/onnxruntime/onnxruntime/test/shared_lib/cuda_ops.cu.o: Relocations in generic ELF (EM: 62)
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/custom_op_library.dir/root/onnxruntime/onnxruntime/test/shared_lib/cuda_ops.cu.o: error adding symbols: file in wrong format
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
gmake[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/custom_op_library.dir/build.make:149: libcustom_op_library.so] Error 1
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:3693: CMakeFiles/custom_op_library.dir/all] Error 2
gmake[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
[  6%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/onnxruntime_mlas.dir/root/onnxruntime/onnxruntime/core/mlas/lib/qladd.cpp.o
[  6%] Built target custom_op_get_const_input_test_library
[  6%] Building CXX object _deps/flatbuffers-build/CMakeFiles/flatc.dir/src/idl_gen_grpc.cpp.o
[  6%] Building CXX object _deps/flatbuffers-build/CMakeFiles/flatc.dir/src/idl_gen_json_schema.cpp.o
[  6%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/onnxruntime_mlas.dir/root/onnxruntime/onnxruntime/core/mlas/lib/qlmul.cpp.o
[  6%] Linking CXX shared module libcustom_op_local_function.so
[  6%] Built target custom_op_local_function
[  6%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/onnxruntime_mlas.dir/root/onnxruntime/onnxruntime/core/mlas/lib/qpostprocessor.cpp.o
[  6%] Building CXX object _deps/flatbuffers-build/CMakeFiles/flatc.dir/src/idl_gen_swift.cpp.o
[  6%] Building CXX object _deps/flatbuffers-build/CMakeFiles/flatc.dir/src/file_name_saving_file_manager.cpp.o
[  6%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/onnxruntime_mlas.dir/root/onnxruntime/onnxruntime/core/mlas/lib/qlgavgpool.cpp.o
[  6%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/onnxruntime_mlas.dir/root/onnxruntime/onnxruntime/core/mlas/lib/qdwconv_kernelsize.cpp.o
[  6%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/onnxruntime_mlas.dir/root/onnxruntime/onnxruntime/core/mlas/lib/sqnbitgemm.cpp.o
[  6%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/onnxruntime_mlas.dir/root/onnxruntime/onnxruntime/core/mlas/lib/flashattn.cpp.o
[  6%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/onnxruntime_mlas.dir/root/onnxruntime/onnxruntime/core/mlas/lib/q4_dq.cpp.o
[  6%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/onnxruntime_mlas.dir/root/onnxruntime/onnxruntime/core/mlas/lib/q4gemm.cpp.o
[  6%] Building ASM object CMakeFiles/onnxruntime_mlas.dir/root/onnxruntime/onnxruntime/core/mlas/lib/aarch64/ConvSymS8KernelDot.S.o
[  6%] Building CXX object _deps/flatbuffers-build/CMakeFiles/flatc.dir/src/file_binary_writer.cpp.o
[  6%] Building CXX object _deps/flatbuffers-build/CMakeFiles/flatc.dir/src/file_writer.cpp.o
[  6%] Building CXX object _deps/flatbuffers-build/CMakeFiles/flatc.dir/src/flatc.cpp.o
[  6%] Building CXX object _deps/flatbuffers-build/CMakeFiles/flatc.dir/src/flatc_main.cpp.o
[  6%] Building ASM object CMakeFiles/onnxruntime_mlas.dir/root/onnxruntime/onnxruntime/core/mlas/lib/aarch64/ConvSymS8KernelDotLd64.S.o
[  6%] Building CXX object _deps/flatbuffers-build/CMakeFiles/flatc.dir/src/binary_annotator.cpp.o
[  6%] Building ASM object CMakeFiles/onnxruntime_mlas.dir/root/onnxruntime/onnxruntime/core/mlas/lib/aarch64/ConvSymU8KernelDot.S.o
[  6%] Building CXX object _deps/flatbuffers-build/CMakeFiles/flatc.dir/src/annotated_binary_text_gen.cpp.o
[  6%] Building CXX object _deps/flatbuffers-build/CMakeFiles/flatc.dir/src/bfbs_gen_lua.cpp.o
[  6%] Building CXX object _deps/flatbuffers-build/CMakeFiles/flatc.dir/src/bfbs_gen_nim.cpp.o
[  6%] Building ASM object CMakeFiles/onnxruntime_mlas.dir/root/onnxruntime/onnxruntime/core/mlas/lib/aarch64/ConvSymS8KernelNeon.S.o
[  7%] Building CXX object _deps/flatbuffers-build/CMakeFiles/flatc.dir/src/code_generators.cpp.o
[  7%] Building CXX object _deps/flatbuffers-build/CMakeFiles/flatc.dir/grpc/src/compiler/cpp_generator.cc.o
[  7%] Building CXX object _deps/flatbuffers-build/CMakeFiles/flatc.dir/grpc/src/compiler/go_generator.cc.o
[  7%] Building ASM object CMakeFiles/onnxruntime_mlas.dir/root/onnxruntime/onnxruntime/core/mlas/lib/aarch64/ConvSymU8KernelNeon.S.o
[  7%] Building ASM object CMakeFiles/onnxruntime_mlas.dir/root/onnxruntime/onnxruntime/core/mlas/lib/aarch64/DepthwiseQConvSymS8KernelNeon.S.o
[  7%] Building ASM object CMakeFiles/onnxruntime_mlas.dir/root/onnxruntime/onnxruntime/core/mlas/lib/aarch64/DepthwiseQConvSymU8KernelNeon.S.o
[  7%] Building ASM object CMakeFiles/onnxruntime_mlas.dir/root/onnxruntime/onnxruntime/core/mlas/lib/aarch64/DepthwiseQConvKernelSize9Neon.S.o
[  7%] Building ASM object CMakeFiles/onnxruntime_mlas.dir/root/onnxruntime/onnxruntime/core/mlas/lib/aarch64/QgemmU8X8KernelNeon.S.o
[  8%] Building ASM object CMakeFiles/onnxruntime_mlas.dir/root/onnxruntime/onnxruntime/core/mlas/lib/aarch64/QgemmS8S8KernelNeon.S.o
[  8%] Building ASM object CMakeFiles/onnxruntime_mlas.dir/root/onnxruntime/onnxruntime/core/mlas/lib/aarch64/QgemmU8X8KernelUdot.S.o
[  8%] Building ASM object CMakeFiles/onnxruntime_mlas.dir/root/onnxruntime/onnxruntime/core/mlas/lib/aarch64/QgemmS8S8KernelSdot.S.o
[  8%] Building ASM object CMakeFiles/onnxruntime_mlas.dir/root/onnxruntime/onnxruntime/core/mlas/lib/aarch64/SgemmKernelNeon.S.o
[  8%] Building ASM object CMakeFiles/onnxruntime_mlas.dir/root/onnxruntime/onnxruntime/core/mlas/lib/aarch64/SgemvKernelNeon.S.o
[  8%] Building ASM object CMakeFiles/onnxruntime_mlas.dir/root/onnxruntime/onnxruntime/core/mlas/lib/aarch64/SymQgemmS8KernelNeon.S.o
[  8%] Building ASM object CMakeFiles/onnxruntime_mlas.dir/root/onnxruntime/onnxruntime/core/mlas/lib/aarch64/SymQgemmS8KernelSdot.S.o
[  8%] Building ASM object CMakeFiles/onnxruntime_mlas.dir/root/onnxruntime/onnxruntime/core/mlas/lib/aarch64/SymQgemmS8KernelSdotLd64.S.o
[  8%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/onnxruntime_mlas.dir/root/onnxruntime/onnxruntime/core/mlas/lib/qgemm_kernel_neon.cpp.o
[  8%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/onnxruntime_mlas.dir/root/onnxruntime/onnxruntime/core/mlas/lib/qgemm_kernel_udot.cpp.o
[  8%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/onnxruntime_mlas.dir/root/onnxruntime/onnxruntime/core/mlas/lib/qgemm_kernel_sdot.cpp.o
[  8%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/onnxruntime_mlas.dir/root/onnxruntime/onnxruntime/core/mlas/lib/sqnbitgemm_kernel_neon.cpp.o
[  8%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/onnxruntime_mlas.dir/root/onnxruntime/onnxruntime/core/mlas/lib/sqnbitgemm_kernel_neon_fp32.cpp.o
[  8%] Building CXX object _deps/flatbuffers-build/CMakeFiles/flatc.dir/grpc/src/compiler/java_generator.cc.o
[  8%] Building CXX object _deps/flatbuffers-build/CMakeFiles/flatc.dir/grpc/src/compiler/python_generator.cc.o
[  8%] Building CXX object _deps/flatbuffers-build/CMakeFiles/flatc.dir/grpc/src/compiler/swift_generator.cc.o
[  8%] Building CXX object _deps/flatbuffers-build/CMakeFiles/flatc.dir/grpc/src/compiler/ts_generator.cc.o
[  8%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/onnxruntime_mlas.dir/root/onnxruntime/onnxruntime/core/mlas/lib/sqnbitgemm_kernel_neon_int8.cpp.o
[  8%] Building ASM object CMakeFiles/onnxruntime_mlas.dir/root/onnxruntime/onnxruntime/core/mlas/lib/aarch64/HalfGemmKernelNeon.S.o
[  8%] Building ASM object CMakeFiles/onnxruntime_mlas.dir/root/onnxruntime/onnxruntime/core/mlas/lib/aarch64/QgemmS8S8KernelSmmla.S.o
[  8%] Building ASM object CMakeFiles/onnxruntime_mlas.dir/root/onnxruntime/onnxruntime/core/mlas/lib/aarch64/QgemmU8X8KernelUmmla.S.o
[  8%] Building ASM object CMakeFiles/onnxruntime_mlas.dir/root/onnxruntime/onnxruntime/core/mlas/lib/aarch64/SbgemmKernelNeon.S.o
[  8%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/onnxruntime_mlas.dir/root/onnxruntime/onnxruntime/core/mlas/lib/activate_fp16.cpp.o
[  8%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/onnxruntime_mlas.dir/root/onnxruntime/onnxruntime/core/mlas/lib/dwconv.cpp.o
[  9%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/onnxruntime_mlas.dir/root/onnxruntime/onnxruntime/core/mlas/lib/halfgemm_kernel_neon.cpp.o
[  9%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/onnxruntime_mlas.dir/root/onnxruntime/onnxruntime/core/mlas/lib/pooling_fp16.cpp.o
[  9%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/onnxruntime_mlas.dir/root/onnxruntime/onnxruntime/core/mlas/lib/qgemm_kernel_smmla.cpp.o
[  9%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/onnxruntime_mlas.dir/root/onnxruntime/onnxruntime/core/mlas/lib/qgemm_kernel_ummla.cpp.o
[  9%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/onnxruntime_mlas.dir/root/onnxruntime/onnxruntime/core/mlas/lib/sbgemm_kernel_neon.cpp.o
[  9%] Linking CXX executable flatc
[  9%] Built target flatc
[  9%] Linking CXX static library libonnxruntime_mlas.a
[  9%] Built target onnxruntime_mlas
gmake: *** [Makefile:146: all] Error 2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/onnxruntime/tools/ci_build/build.py", line 2971, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/root/onnxruntime/tools/ci_build/build.py", line 2861, in main
    build_targets(args, cmake_path, build_dir, configs, num_parallel_jobs, args.target)
  File "/root/onnxruntime/tools/ci_build/build.py", line 1729, in build_targets
    run_subprocess(cmd_args, env=env)
  File "/root/onnxruntime/tools/ci_build/build.py", line 860, in run_subprocess
    return run(*args, cwd=cwd, capture_stdout=capture_stdout, shell=shell, env=my_env)
  File "/root/onnxruntime/tools/python/util/run.py", line 49, in run
    completed_process = subprocess.run(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 526, in run
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/root/Downloads/cmake-3.31.0-linux-x86_64/bin/cmake', '--build', 'aarch64-build-gpu/Release', '--config', 'Release', '--', '-j8']' returned non-zero exit status 2.


I also tried some extra steps from https://github.com/microsoft/onnxruntime/issues/1777
sudo cp /usr/include/cudnn.h /usr/local/cuda/include/
sudo cp /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libcudnn* /usr/local/cuda/lib64/

but it fails in the same way.
Do you have any suggestions?

You clearly are mixing host and cross compile target object files. clean everything and try again. If you still have the error, then you obviously haven’t propagated the cross compile settings correctly to all parts of the build configuration

Thanks @talonmies for the suggestion. I tried many times, with the same error all the times. As per your other suggestion, I just followed the official guides from Nvidia on how to install the cross-compilation toolchain. Do you have any other guides?

The cross compilation toolchain is probably fine, it is the cmake which is not handling the cross compilation correctly.  If you are confident you had a truely clean build and are winding  up with host objects,  you have no choice but to deep dive in the build logs and makefiles to work out where they are coming from
